# Filter of pythonaddins.OpenDialog window

Tags: arcpy, python-addin

I need to make a pythonaddins.OpenDialog to select a "Folder location"
What is the filternto written in this statement

```
Folder_Location = pythonaddins.OpenDialog("Please select a folder to store the project and files in", False, "","Select a Folder", ????????,???????)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `pythonaddins.OpenDialog` to select a folder.  According to the [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/python-addins/the-pythonaddins-module.htm), it is for selecting GIS datasets, not any file/folder:

> Opens a dialog box to choose one or more GIS datasets.
>
> This function returns the full path of the dataset chosen. If multiple datasets are chosen, it returns a list of full paths. There is no filtering of the input datasets (for example, filter only for point feature classes).

Comment: If we want the user to select a folder, would our only option be to create a geoprocessing tool for this purpose?